# Synonym for "manipulation"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

is there a synonym for "manipulation" that carries the connotation of "influence by artful means" but lacks the connotation of "physical interaction involving hands"?

Comment: I've no doubt that *most* uses of ***manipulation*** are metaphorical, and it's very likely that a significant proportion of native speakers who are perfectly familiar with that metaphorical sense don't even *know* the literal one. In short, this is probably a non-issue for native speakers, because ordinarily the connotation "physical interaction involving hands" simply doesn't arise .

Comment: ...just as we don't normally interpret ***interference*** as carrying connotations of ***inappropriate sexual touching of [a minor's] genitals***.

Comment: Yeah, I gotta second @FumbleFingers here. When you say someone is, for example, "manipulative", you're not trying to suggest they actively touch people and/or use their hands to achieve said manipulation.

Comment: @AleksandrH: If you're trying to manipulate this discussion thread by putting words into my mouth, I just hope you washed your hands first! :)

Comment: I don't know—my massage therapist likes to manipulate me on a regular basis . . . ;)

Comment: @JasonBassford - I guess that’s ok as long as there’s no interference.

Comment: What did a thesaurus suggest?

Comment: If you want a synonym for something, consult a thesaurus.

Answer (score 0):

n. **sway**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sway)

> n.
>   2. Influence or control:

Comment: i'm looking for a noun

Comment: @zedecks  aye aye!

Comment: IMO, "sway" doesn't adequately convey artfulness or purpose

Comment: and on a meta note, for the sake of preserving the continuity of the discussion, i think it's preferable when editing a response to leave the original text in place with strikethroughs.  as it is, it took me a while to notice you had edited your response at all.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to provide [coercion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coercion), but that implies intimidation. The question specifically made use of the term "artful means"—which is something more subtle and intellectual.

[**Finagle**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finagle):

> **finagled**; **finagling**
>
> to obtain by indirect or involved means · *finagle* a ride home
>
> to obtain by trickery · *finagled* his way into the concert
>
> to use devious or dishonest methods to achieve one's ends · A con man *finagled* my neighbor out of $400.
>
> let me look at my schedule and see if I can't *finagle* a visit to the museum

Edited to add an alternative in the same vein.

[**Mastermind**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mastermind):

> a person who supplies the directing or creative intelligence for a project
> a person who plans and organizes something
>
> the real mastermind behind the embezzlement scheme
> They masterminded a unique solution to the problem.

Comment: i'm not sure if i can adequately explain why, but "finagling" doesn't seem to be quite what i'm after.  i think it's that the implication of deviousness or trickery conveys _too much_ artfulness.

Comment: @zedecks I updated my answer with a different word, and will leave it to others if it's still not quite right. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to add puppet master because  puppet master controls from behind the scenes, manipulating people and things like a puppeteer operating a puppet.
http://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/puppet-master/

Comment: how is "puppet master" synonymous with "manipulation"?  "puppet mastery" makes considerably more sense but still seems pretty wide of the mark.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one last attempt, in a different sense. If this is also not what you're after, you will need to provide some specific sentence examples with "blanks" so that the meaning you're after is clearer.

[**Beguiled**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beguile):

> transitive
>
> 1 : hoodwink · *beguiled* her classmates into doing the work for her
> 2 : to engage the interest of by or as if by guile · His seductive voice *beguiled* the audience.
> 3 : to lead by deception · *beguiled* into ambush
>
> intranstive
>
> to deceive by wiles · had intended to *beguile*

Something can also be [**beguiling**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beguiling):

> agreeably or charmingly attractive or pleasing · a *beguiling* manner · a *beguiling* aroma

Answer (score -1):

Handling:
the action of touching with the hands (or the skillful use of the hands) or by the use of mechanical means

Comment: Erm... OP specifically asked for an expression for which the "literal" sense ***doesn't*** relate to touching with hands.